# How to prepare updated attributes hash for update external service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asterisk

I want to achive something like below. How to get `new_attributes` hash?

```
after_save :update_asterisk_contact

def update_asterisk_contact
  changes # => [{ "sip_id"=>[334, 355], "updated_at"=>[Tue, 29 Oct 2013 16:03:17 CET +01:00, Tue, 29 Oct 2013 16:08:31 CET +01:00]}]
  # new_attributes => {'sip_id'=> 355}
  client = Asterisk::Client.instance
  client.update(self.id, new_attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only need to use `attributes` method:

```
def update_asterisk_contact
  client = Asterisk::Client.instance
  client.update(id, attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To only update the changed attributes:

```
def update_asterisk_contact
  client = Asterisk::Client.instance
  client.update(id, attributes.slice(changed_attributes.keys))
end
```

`attributes` contains all the models attributes with their new values. `changed_attributes` are all the attributes that changed (but with their old values), so we limit to the attributes that have changed.